# Allow creation of a limited user only with CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I want the Admin user to not have the ability to create users with the role of Super Admin but still be able to create other Admins and Regular Users. How do I accomplish this? Here is my Ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.super_admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.admin?
      can :manage, [Article, Comment]
      can [:destroy, :update], User, :role_id => 2 # If Admin
      can [:destroy, :update], User, :role_id => 3 # If User
      can :read, User
      can :create, User
    elsif user.user_regular?
      #cannot :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
      #can :manage, :all

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cannot` with in `admin` block like `cannot :creat, User, :role_id => 1 # let 1 is super admin role id`. You can get more info about combine ability [at here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#combining-abilities)